# Get last non-empty cell from range input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Up until now, I was using an answer from SF to fetch the last non empty row from a range:

```
=INDEX( FILTER( A4:D ; NOT( ISBLANK( A4:A ) ) ) ; ROWS( FILTER( A4:A ; NOT( ISBLANK( A4:A ) ) ) ) )
```

Since I started using it quite often, I opted for a script instead:

```js
/* E.g. GETLASTNECELL(A4:A) */
function GETLASTNECELL(input) {
 
  if (!Array.isArray(input)) {
    throw new Error("Must be range")
  }
  if (input.map(col => col.length).sort()[0] !== 1) {
    throw new Error("Range must be a single column")
  }
  
  const col = input
    .map(row => row[0])   // get value
    .filter(val => typeof val !== 'undefined' && val.toString().length > 0) // empty
    return col[col.length - 1]
}
```

The issue is that the function is really slow...Is it just a by-product of Google Scripts lifecycle ? The native formulas approach displays the result in an instant. (Tested on a tiny 40x40 spreadsheet)

Read:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8161172/2124535
- [How to grab all non-empty cell data in row - Google Sheets Script Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055031/how-to-grab-all-non-empty-cell-data-in-row-google-sheets-script-editor/48055416)

Comment: For clarification purposes. You said you tested the formula on a `40x40` spreadsheet. I tested your formula and realized that it works only for a single column. If you see the error message you have `Error("Range must be a single column")`. How do you execute it? What do you pass as a parameter?

Comment: "Real" range e.g. `GETLASTNECELL(A4:A)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, custom functions / scripts are slower than their equivalent built-in functions.

Most built-in functions runs on client-side while custom functions / scripts runs on server-side.

Comment: Ah thanks, thought as much :( I wish there was a way to create a native alias or something similar.

Comment: You might use Google Apps Script to insert your formulas i.e. create a custom menu. Going further you might use a dialog to ask for the range references or use R1C1 notation :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach of passing the range as a `string` instead and let me know if it works faster for you as it does for me:

```
function GETLASTNECELL(input) {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const lrow = sh.getLastRow();
  const Avals = sh.getRange(input+lrow).getValues();
  const value  = Avals[Avals.reverse().findIndex(c=>c[0]!='')]
  return value;
}
```

**Usage:**

[image]

**Regular function:**

```
function myFunction() {
  const input = "A1:A";
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  const lrow = sh.getLastRow();
  const Avals = sh.getRange(input+lrow).getValues();
  const value  = Avals[Avals.reverse().findIndex(c=>c[0]!='')]
  return value;
}
```

and execute it from the script editor (click on the run button) or create a macro menu to execute it from the spreadsheet itself.

Comment: My lack of understanding was the main issue. I thought there was a way to run gs script locally, just like native functions.

Comment: @nathan do you want to run it as a regular function ? Namely, execute it from the script editor or some kind of macro menu ? If yes, let me know and I will modify my answer.

Comment: The function is used in the spreadsheet, I don't need to run it manually so this might not the be case.

Comment: @nathan does my first code works faster then ? If not, it is fine but I am not sure if you tried it out.

Comment: I did, since my spreadsheets aren't really big the performance is pretty much the same (I didn't benchmark but the issue is server-side communication)

Comment: @nathan consider upvoting if you found the solution helpful :)